# Seeking administrative boundaries for neighborhood councils (NCs) of Nowshera, Pakistan

Tags: shapefile, data, administrative-boundaries, pakistan

I am trying to find administrative boundary shapefiles for neighborhood councils (NCs) of Nowshera (Pakistan). The only available data I could find was only up to union-council dataset. Has anyone acquired or know of that kind of dataset?

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.